# How do I open .wmv files with OpenCV on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, video, wmv

I am trying to open a Windows Media Video file on a macintosh using OpenCV.  To view this video in MacOS I had to install a player called Flip4Mac.  I am assuming that this came with the codecs for decoding WMV.  Is there something I can now do to get OpenCV to open the videos using the codec?

In python/opencv2 opening a video should be super easy:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('0009.wmv')
```

But I get this:

```
WARNING: Couldn't read movie file 0009.wmv
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV video on OS X is very buggy in my experience. However try installing ffmpeg using Homebrew (I also recommend installing OpenCV using homebrew if you haven't done that already):

```
$ brew install ffmpeg
```

On Mavericks I've had all kinds of problems getting OpenCV and ffmpeg work together, so you might want to try installing ffmpeg and opencv in different orders, if this does not work. But for me now the following code works, provided that there is a file named `test.wmv` in the directory:

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("test.wmv")

while True:
    vid.grab()

    retval, image = vid.retrieve()

    if not retval:
        break

    cv2.imshow("Test", image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the problem before and it was simply that VideoCapture needed the full path to the file and not a relative path.

hope this helps.